# Confusion in MIPS code

Tags: load, mips, memory-address

While going through the MIPS code I got some confusion. Code is shown as follows

```
.data
 key: .ascii "key: "              # "key:  \n"
char: .asciiz "  \n"               
 .text
 .globl main
main:
 jal getchar     

la $a0, char                    # $a0 contains address of char variable (" \n")
  sb $v0, ($a0)                   # replace " " in char with v0, which is read_character (X) 
 la $a0, key                     # now a0 will contain, address of "key: "  "X\n"
```

What I dont understand is that how load address instruction works. First a0 contained address of char variable. In next line we are storing value of v0 in that location. there is no offset with (`$a0`), is that assumed to be 0 like in 0(`$a0`)? Why only the " " empty space is replaced with v0, and why not the "\n" get replaced?  or It may also have been the case that both the empty space and \n character get replced by v0.

Secondly when we load the address of key in a0, the previous address should be overwritten. a0 should have contained the address of key only, but from  comment it seems that the two strings are concatenated. How does that happen.

Answer (score 1):

`sb` stores one byte in memory.

To answer your questions in detail:

```
there is no offset with ($a0), is that assumed to be 0 like in 0($a0)?
```

yes.

```
Why only the " " empty space is replaced with v0, and why not the "\n" get replaced?
```

`sb` only stores one byte, in this case the byte on address `char`, which is a space. The newline is the next byte.

```
or It may also have been the case that both the empty space and \n character get replced by v0.
```

No, only one byte.

```
a0 should have contained the address of key only, but from comment it seems that the two strings are concatenated. How does that happen.
```

Yes, $a0 contains the address `key`, but a string is closed by a null character. When you do

```
key: .ascii "key: "
```

the bytes represented by `"key: "` are placed in memory, without a null character at the end (because .ascii is used). Next, the instruction `char: .asciiz "  \n"` places the bytes of `"  \n"` in memory, after the bytes of the proevious one. In this case, they are null terminated, because .asciiz is used (instead of .ascii). So, the address `key` is pointing to a string that is null terminated after the newline. Or, `key` is the address of the first character of the string.

To make it more clear

```
.asciiz "abc"
```

and

```
.ascii "a"
.ascii "b"
.asciiz "c"
```

are the same.